# Unreachable link to MetaFilter in Help Center

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, help-center

One of the sections of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), namely [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), lists the below link. It is not reachable for me — my browser keeps on trying to load the page.

> (The above section was adapted from [MetaFilter’s FAQ](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter).)

Can we update this link to MetaFilter, or remove it?

Comment: The link works fine for me, FWIW.

Comment: It's doing multiple refresh/redirects for me in both Safari and Chrome (Mac 10.11.2). The source I can capture is trying to redirect to https via javascript if the protocol is http. However, it does it even when I'm accessing via https.

Comment: @Arun: This issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can reproduce, so I reached out to the Metafilter staff about the issue. I will update this post with any news.

- **2017-12-26 03:05 PM CST** -- Message sent to Metafilter staff
- **2017-12-26 03:14 PM CST** -- I can no longer reproduce the issue. Temporary glitch? Waiting for official response.
- **2017-12-26 03:28 PM CST** -- Received response from Metafilter that they will take a look.
- **2017-12-27 10:31 AM CST** -- Official response from Metafilter:

  > "Thanks for pointing this out. It took a bit of poking around to reproduce it, but it should now be fixed."

Comment: I can still reproduce the infinite loop issue, 12 hours later. Note that I'm using "HTTPS Everywhere" and "Privacy Badger" extensions for Chrome.

Comment: Does their [permalink](https://faq.metafilter.com/70/chatfilter) cause the same problem?

Comment: permalink is working fine. now even the original link is working fine

Comment: @Cœur Could you clear your cache and see if the problem is resolved? http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @wizzwizz4, as commented by Arun Vinoth, and as described by the timestamp of the edit of Cory, the issue was resolved _after_ my comment.

Comment: @Cœur Should now be fixed != is fixed; considering that it worked for some people and not for others, it might still not have worked for you despite working for others.